# Simple geometric reasoning problem

Tags: geometry

Note: This is actually a problem that I need to solve in a program that I am currently writing so it may not be solvable. If so, please explain why.

Let's imagine there are two circles, one larger than another (with centers a and b).
The radius of the larger circle is n cm long.
The position of the larger circle is (w, x)
The position of the smaller circle is (y, z)
The smaller circle's center is located on the circumference of the larger circle.
A tangent exists from point d (which is directly above b) to point c.
The angle abd is e degrees. (not sure if this is necessary)
EDIT: the length of a-c is f cm.

Find the coordinates of point c (using any of the aforementioned variables)

see diagram : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take $n,e,f,w,x$ as the given data (not sure if the coordinates of $d$ or $a$  would be more appropriate).

First we find (assuming for the moment that $b$ is in the origin) that point $a$ has coordinates $(n\sin e,n\cos e)$ and the line segment $ac$ is orthogonal to $ba$, so in direction $(\cos e,-\sin e)$. As the length of it is given, we obtain as final result (taking into account the correct coordinates of $b$)
$$ c=(w+n\sin e+f\cos e,x+n\cos e-f\sin e).$$

---

If we start with coordinates of $a$ and $b$ instead, we can write
$$c=\left(y+\frac{(z-x)f}{n},z+\frac{(y-w)f}{n}\right) $$

Comment: Thankyou, this is a very well explained answer :)